Next.js dynamic internationalization pathing for my project
Ok so i have this project that i am making in Next.js which utilizes App Routing and Crystallize which is GraphQL driven CMS, the folders are in english but i need to integrate internationalization into my project, and the way that it works now is that you can do api calls based on language, but inside crystallize when the language changes so does the path of the fetch.
Now we have built a way to fetch all of the links with 1 generic path, but when i want to fetch pages inside my app it becomes difficult because maybe i would like to fetch the "about-us" page, in english this is what it would look like.
In our code base we have about-us > page.tsx
const { components } = await fetchAboutUsPage("/genericRootPath/about-us", "en", apiClient);

But then let's say i change the lng to Norwegian and want to fetch the Norwegian contents.
It would look something like this.
const { components } = await fetchAboutUsPage("/genericRootPath/om-oss", "no", apiClient);

So the root path stays the same because i defined it as such in the CMS whilst the endpoint changes based on the language provided.
The issue with the Norwegian one is that our folder is still called about-us > page.tsx, so the question is, are there any resources i can utilize to localize the folder name or redirect the user.
The only solution i have found is to just declare them inside the i18n locale json files for different languages.
Kind of new to internationalization so ive tried the standard i18n route but this with dynamic pathing is difficult.

I do not have permission make a comment here. Are you looking for something like this?
Let say you have a route like this,
http://localhost:3000/dashboard
so you page.tsx will be http://localhost:3000/dashboard/page.tsx
I know how to change the language using a url parameter for the language,
for an example:
http://localhost:3000/en/dashboard/page.tsx --> will be in English
http://localhost:3000/de/dashboard/page.tsx --> will be in German
Is this what you explain as a "dynamic internationalization pathing" ?
If so please let me know, I will provide answer by editing this.
